# lipo can't open input file (no such file or directory) xcode

Tags: ios, frameworks

i am getting this error when i am trying to make .framework file using the instruction in http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework.html..

Did anyone encountered this before? ..

Comment: iam struck in middle of making a framework

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have done this. Replace "FW_NAME" with your Framework name, In my case "iOSBundle"

The reason other than you are getting this is the source code dependency problems. To analyze this just add 2 files ie; appDelegate .h and .m and see if the framework is constructed or not.

Check that VALID_ARCHS has been correctly set.
Build active architecture is NO

[See this link](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/)I have generated a framework and have been using that. It is quite frustrating But a good step.